# Type infering or adding complex type checking based from array

Tags: typescript

I'm unsure how to add type checking to the register function, as it currently accepts an array of Module[], allowing any options for a module. I'd like to impose some restrictions without resorting to type assertion. Any guidance on achieving this would be appreciated

```
register([
    {
        use: NumberModule,
        options: {
            // I expected that type checking is working without type assertion 
            numb: 1
        } as NumberModuleOptions // I'd like to remove this assertion
    },
    {
        use: StringModule,
        options: {
            // I expected that type checking is working without type assertion 
            str: 'hello'
        } as StringModuleOptions // I'd like to remove this 
    }
])
```

Full code

```
interface Module<Options, Contructor = ModuleContructor<Options> {
    use: Contructor
    options: Options
}


type ModuleContructor<Type> = new (...args: any[]) => ModuleInterface<Type>


interface ModuleInterface<Type> {
    handle(data: Type): void
}



interface NumberModuleOptions {
    numb: number
}

class NumberModule implements ModuleInterface<NumberModuleOptions> {
    handle(data: NumberModuleOptions): void {
        console.log(data)
    }

}

interface StringModuleOptions {
    str: string
}

class StringModule implements ModuleInterface<StringModuleOptions> {
    handle(data: StringModuleOptions): void {
        console.log(data)
    }

}



function register(modules: Module<unknown>[]): void {
 // some implementation
}
```

Comment: What's the issue / question?

Comment: updated question

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOrvlW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz - yes it does exactly what I need

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to have been enough time for you to test thoroughly enough to be sure.  Could you check in some depth?  I've had the problem before where someone gives me a "oops, actually this doesn't work" while I'm in the middle of an answer.  I'll check back later.

Comment: @jcalz - I've double-checked and tested your solution, it aligns perfectly with my requirements. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Module<unknown>[]` then `register()` will accept more than you'd like for `modules`, since `unknown` accepts anything.  Really what you want to do is accept an [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) like `[Module<X>, Module<Y>, Module<Z>]`, where `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are inferred.  This can be accomplished by making `register()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `T` corresponding to `[X, Y, Z]` and where `modules` is of a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) that wraps each element of `T` with `Module<T>`.  Conceptually that looks like:

```
function register<T extends any[]>(
  modules: [...{ [I in keyof T]: Module<T[I]>}]): void {
  // some implementation
}
```

which is a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to give the compiler a hint that you want to infer a tuple instead of an array.

Unfortunately this is still too permissive; `Module<X>`, which is really `Module<X, ModuleContructor<X>>`, depends on `X` both in the `use` property and the `options` property. You want to infer `X` from the `use` property and then just *check* `options` against it.  But TypeScript is more than happy to try to infer `X` from both of them.  To fix this we need to break the inference on `options`; we'd like the first `X` in `Module<X, ModuleContructor<X>>` to be a *non-inferential type parameter usage* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829).  Like `Module<NoInfer<X>, ModuleContructor<X>>` where `NoInfer` is some magical inference blocker.  There's no native implementation of `NoInfer` in TypeScript, but that GitHub issue gives various user-defined versions that work for some use cases.  Here's one:

```
type NoInfer<T> = T extends infer U ? U : never
```

And now we can write `register()` like this:

```
function register<T extends any[]>(modules: [...{ [I in keyof T]:
  Module<NoInfer<T[I]>, ModuleContructor<T[I]>> }]): void {
  // some implementation
}
```

Let's try it:

```
register([
  {
    use: NumberModule,
    options: {
      numb: 1
    }
  },
  {
    use: StringModule,
    options: {
      str: 'hello'
    }
  }
]); // okay

register([
  {
    use: NumberModule,
    options: {
      numb: 1
    }
  },
  {
    use: StringModule,
    options: {
      oops: 'hello' // error!
    }
  }
]);
```

Looks good. The compiler accepts correct inputs and rejects incorrect inputs.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#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-f6Aka2yUPCtVmtQcKpM4nlRqTSYj4vhoM5DCNRIf2dG4rmQABGED90ZYCuggv8tCtRUtSQ51kCMW1wPgoURWQAByboIFwaliPgpkVCZLI7Ffasak-b94NQgCoSA+DcOOLQIJUKCtDgkkEN9LCnV-dQ0O5a0YXE0C8L4gicKMRJSPIyizwvaAoA4ABCajGSULIgA)